# MS SQL Hook and Operators not importing into Airflow

Tags: airflow, importerror

Trying to import the mssql hook and operator into my dag but I keep getting this error from Airflow.

I'm currently importing with the newest syntax:

`from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook`

`from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator`

and I'm getting this import error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/hevo_dag.py", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.hooks.mssql import MsSqlHook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql'
```

Comment: Have you installed apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql?

Comment: Yep it says I have it successfully installed but there was an error message that said "ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
apache-airflow-backport-providers-microsoft-mssql 2020.11.23 requires apache-airflow~=1.10, but you have apache-airflow 2.3.2 which is incompatible."

Comment: You need to do `pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql` not `apache-airflow-backport-providers-microsoft-mssql`

Answer (score 1):

To import the operator you need to do:

**For Airflow>=2.0:**
you need to use [Mssql provider package](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql
```

**For Airflow<2.0:**
you need to use [Mssql backport provider package](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-microsoft-mssql/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-microsoft-mssql
```

In your code it's the same import path (regardless of the package). Airflow backported the provider to ease migration from Airflow 1 to Airflow 2 so upon upgrading you will not need to change the import paths.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up uninstalling the backport provider package and installing the other provider package but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error, do you know what might be the issue?